# With a jQuery Slideshow, how to show captions with mouseenter/hover?

Tags: jquery, html, slideshow, caption

I'm fairly new to jQuery and right now, I'm working on a school project where I'm making a small website. I don't think we're allowed to use any plug-ins, because this project is about showing that we can understand and use jQuery independently at a basic level.

Anyway, I managed (with the help of [Snook's "Simplest jQuery Slideshow" Tutorial](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/simplest-jquery-slideshow)) to create a simple slideshow.

Now I want to add some functionality to this slideshow. I want to use captions in some way, like showing caption while hovering or on mouseenter. I tried searching and testing various things, but guess I'm not experienced enough just yet to find the solution. "Adapting code to another context", like finding something that *could* work for me as well is something I still find a bit difficult.

So, if I want some kind of caption to be shown while hovering the image, what solution would be the best? I'm open-minded, as long as the code isn't too complex.

Here's the HTML:

Some text.

```
<div id="gallery">
    <img src="img/gallery0.jpg" />
    <img src="img/gallery1.jpg" />
    <img src="img/gallery2.jpg" />
    <img src="img/gallery3.jpg" />
    <img src="img/gallery4.jpg" />
</div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$('#gallery img:gt(0)').hide(); //Hiding all but the first img

setInterval(function() { 
    $('#gallery :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('#gallery'); 
//Fade out first image, fade in the next and add the first image to the end of #gallery
}, 4000);
```

To see how this slideshow works, here's my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8tkEM/).

I must have been living in some kind of dream, thinking something this would work;

```
$('#caption').hide();
$('#gallery').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#caption').show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#caption').show(); you missed '$'

$('#gallery').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#caption').show();
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8tkEM/ 
Just added 2 random images, so you can see how it works.